# Can't login using web api identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to implement a web api for authentication in a local project and to learn that process I'm using asp.net's tutorial [Here](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api)
The errors I'm getting with this mirror the issues I'm having with my own so it felt like a good starting point to troubleshoot. The only changes I've made are pointing it to my local SQL db.

I don't like the naming convention of the tables it creates, so I added an override to specify the table names that I got from an online resource. When I add this override it's throwing a status code 500 internal server error:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("User").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserID");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("RoleID");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserClaimID");
    }
}
```

How can I keep the functionality and change the table names?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem. I've changed my table names although did not bother the the properties. What are you getting locally when the 500 is returned - anything from debugging or a stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that I ran it once, it created the default table schema, then I ran it again and it was expecting a code migration to update the tables. I expected it to generate new tables, so that was the confusion. I deleted the entire database and kept the same override method in place and it worked.

Comment: Now I have an entirely new issue, but that'll be a new question :(

Comment: Yer was 10 seconds away from posting that as a possible :)

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine and a 500 error is not enough info for you or us to go on. 500 is returned for pretty much any exception in a Web API.

It would be worthwhile following this guide: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling to help identify the root cause of this and future issues in your Web API.